# paypal auto refund script?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I need to refund a list of transactions to buyers, but instead of doing it manually by going into paypal account I need to write a script from my site so that it will automatically refund those payments. what is the URL that i have to send necessary details from a form or a link.
Please  tell me a way or  give me a proper link

Answer (score 2):

You would use the [RefundTransaction API](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/refundtransaction-api-operation-nvp) for that.  You may also need to make use of [TransactionSearch](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/transactionsearch-api-operation-nvp) to find the transaction ID of orders you need to refund if you don't already have them.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. but i want to now how should i write the script, I mean if i'm submitting a form with data what is the action (url) to send